# how to get address of a Reference in UNo?

Tags: c++, openoffice.org, uno

In [**Uno**](http://udk.openoffice.org/) suppose I have Interface of UNO type.  I need to access its value or address.  Which method should I call?

Comment: [Uno](http://www.amazon.com/Mattel-42003-Uno-Card-Game/dp/B00004TZY8)?

Comment: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno/CLI ?

Comment: Mr James UNO Means UNIVERSAL NETWORK OBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

Like any C++ object, you get the address of an object with `&`. A reference itself doesn't have an address, but you can still use `&` to get the address of the object refered to.

"value" is a bit more complex. What's the value of an `iLaunchRocket*` interface? Many interfaces offer only functions and do not have (publicly visible) data. In such cases, the notion of a "value" is tricky.